# Tensorflow GPU Threading

Tags: multithreading, gpu, tensorflow

I'm trying to run tensorflow app using GPU. But, I'm not sure that GPU is automatically making process of threading. Could I control the GPU threads through tensorflow framework? How can I sure that GPU is working efficiently means nearly all threads are working?